# Python: Choose the n points better distributed from a bunch of points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a numpy array of points in an XY plane like:
[image: distribution]

I want to select the n points (let's say 100) better distributed from all these points. This is, I want the density of points to be constant anywhere.

Something like this:

[image]

Is there any pythonic way or any numpy/scipy function to do this?

Comment: What does 'better distributed' mean? Are they the n points furthest from the mean?

Comment: I would like to have a constant density of points anywhere...

Comment: "100 points which the sum of all distances between them is maximum." and "I would like to have a constant density of points anywhere." don't really go together. The first will I think look like a ring of points around the edges of this bunch.

Comment: I've just edited my answer... I hope it's clearer now

Comment: You should give a MWE (Minimal Working Example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you give a specific criterion for defining "better distributed" we can't give a definite answer.

The phrase "constant density of points anywhere" is also misleading, because you have to specify the empirical method for calculating density. Are you approximating it on a grid? If so, the grid size will matter, and points near the boundary won't be correctly represented.

A different approach might be as follows:

1. Calculate the distance matrix between all pairs of points
2. Treating this distance matrix as a weighted network, calculate some measure of centrality for each point in the data, such as [eigenvalue centrality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality#Using_the_adjacency_matrix_to_find_eigenvector_centrality), [Betweenness centrality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality) or [Bonacich centrality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katz_centrality).
3. Order the points in descending order according to the centrality measure, and keep the first 100.
4. Repeat steps 1-4 possibly using a different notion of "distance" between points and with different centrality measures.

Many of these functions are provided directly by SciPy, NetworkX, and scikits.learn and will work directly on a NumPy array.

If you are definitely committed to thinking of the problem in terms of regular spacing and grid density, you might take a look at [quasi-Monte Carlo methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Monte_Carlo_method). In particular, you could try to compute the convex hull of the set of points and then apply a QMC technique to regularly sample from anywhere within that convex hull. But again, this privileges the exterior of the region, which should be sampled far less than the interior.

Yet another interesting approach would be to simply run the K-means algorithm on the scattered data, with a fixed number of clusters K=100. After the algorithm converges, you'll have 100 points from your space (the mean of each cluster). You could repeat this several times with different random starting points for the cluster means and then sample from that larger set of possible means. Since your data do not appear to actually cluster into 100 components naturally, the convergence of this approach won't be very good and may require running the algorithm for a large number of iterations. This also has the downside that the resulting set of 100 points are not necessarily points that come form the observed data, and instead will be local averages of many points.

Answer (score 5):

@EMS is very correct that you should give a lot of thought to exactly what you want.

There more sophisticated ways to do this (EMS's suggestions are very good!), but a brute-force-ish approach is to bin the points onto a regular, rectangular grid and draw a random point from each bin.

The major downside is that you won't get the number of points you ask for. Instead, you'll get some number smaller than that number.

A bit of creative indexing with `pandas` makes this "gridding" approach quite easy, though you can certainly do it with "pure" numpy, as well.

As an example of the simplest possible, brute force, grid approach: (There's a lot we could do better, here.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

total_num = 100000
x, y = np.random.normal(0, 1, (2, total_num))

# We'll always get fewer than this number for two reasons.
# 1) We're choosing a square grid, and "subset_num" may not be a perfect square
# 2) There won't be data in every cell of the grid
subset_num = 1000

# Bin points onto a rectangular grid with approximately "subset_num" cells
nbins = int(np.sqrt(subset_num))
xbins = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), nbins+1)
ybins = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), nbins+1)

# Make a dataframe indexed by the grid coordinates.
i, j = np.digitize(y, ybins), np.digitize(x, xbins)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, y=y), index=[i, j])

# Group by which cell the points fall into and choose a random point from each
groups = df.groupby(df.index)
new = groups.agg(lambda x: np.random.permutation(x)[0])

# Plot the results
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
axes[0].plot(x, y, 'k.')
axes[0].set_title('Original $(n={})$'.format(total_num))
axes[1].plot(new.x, new.y, 'k.')
axes[1].set_title('Subset $(n={})$'.format(len(new)))
plt.setp(axes, aspect=1, adjustable='box-forced')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Loosely based on @EMS's suggestion in a comment, here's another approach.

We'll calculate the density of points using a kernel density estimate, and then use the inverse of that as the probability that a given point will be chosen.

`scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` is not optimized for this use case (or for large numbers of points in general).  It's the bottleneck here. It's possible to write a more optimized version for this specific use case in several ways (approximations, special case here of pairwise distances, etc). However, that's beyond the scope of this particular question. Just be aware that for this specific example with 1e5 points, it will take a minute or two to run.

The advantage of this method is that you get the exact number of points that you asked for. The disadvantage is that you are likely to have local clusters of selected points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

total_num = 100000
subset_num = 1000
x, y = np.random.normal(0, 1, (2, total_num))

# Let's approximate the PDF of the point distribution with a kernel density
# estimate. scipy.stats.gaussian_kde is slow for large numbers of points, so
# you might want to use another implementation in some cases.
xy = np.vstack([x, y])
dens = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

# Try playing around with this weight. Compare 1/dens,  1-dens, and (1-dens)**2
weight = 1 / dens
weight /= weight.sum()

# Draw a sample using np.random.choice with the specified probabilities.
# We'll need to view things as an object array because np.random.choice
# expects a 1D array.
dat = xy.T.ravel().view([('x', float), ('y', float)])
subset = np.random.choice(dat, subset_num, p=weight)

# Plot the results
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
axes[0].scatter(x, y, c=dens, edgecolor='')
axes[0].set_title('Original $(n={})$'.format(total_num))
axes[1].plot(subset['x'], subset['y'], 'k.')
axes[1].set_title('Subset $(n={})$'.format(len(subset)))
plt.setp(axes, aspect=1, adjustable='box-forced')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You could modify this to get just the 100 points as follows: for each grid cell that is non-empty, let the probability of choosing that grid cell be proportional to how many points are in the cell. Then, randomly draw a cell, and from that cell, randomly draw one point. Repeat 100 times. The result will still be pseudorandom, and hence have clumps that a pure quasi-Monte Carlo low discrepancy sequence would not, but this is a very easy-to-implement approach that could give good results.

Comment: This might be accomplishable succinctly with `np.random.choice` using group sizes to make the probabilities, and then using `np.random.choice` again on the group itself, instead of `permutation` which forms an array of all the points in the cell. Something like `np.random.choice(np.random.choice(groups, 1, p=[some_size_thing_here]), 1)`

Comment: @EMS - Good idea! One approach along those lines is to approximate the PDF of the point distribution with a kernel density estimate, and then use the inverse of that as the probability that a given point will be drawn.  I'll add an example.

Answer (score 1):

This method to iteratively pick the point from the remaining points which has the lowest minimum distance to the already picked points has terrible time complexity, but produces pretty uniformly distributed results:

```
from numpy import array, argmax, ndarray
from numpy.ma import vstack
from numpy.random import normal, randint
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist


def well_spaced_points(points: ndarray, num_points: int):
    """
    Pick `num_points` well-spaced points from `points` array.

    :param points: An m x n array of m n-dimensional points.
    :param num_points: The number of points to pick.
    :rtype: ndarray
    :return: A num_points x n array of points from the original array.
    """
    # pick a random point
    current_point_index = randint(0, num_points)
    picked_points = array([points[current_point_index]])
    remaining_points = vstack((
        points[: current_point_index],
        points[current_point_index + 1:]
    ))
    # while there are more points to pick
    while picked_points.shape[0] < num_points:
        # find the furthest point to the current point
        distance_pk_rmn = cdist(picked_points, remaining_points)
        min_distance_pk = distance_pk_rmn.min(axis=0)
        i_furthest = argmax(min_distance_pk)
        # add it to picked points and remove it from remaining
        picked_points = vstack((
            picked_points,
            remaining_points[i_furthest]
        ))
        remaining_points = vstack((
            remaining_points[: i_furthest],
            remaining_points[i_furthest + 1:]
        ))

    return picked_points
```

[image: 200 / 1000 points]